# How to add new property of some objects in the array that doesn't have the specified property? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I am trying to add a new property to the objects in the array which don't have that property.

```
const updatedArray = items.filter(item => !item.hasBox)...
```

What should be the rest part after the filtering for adding the new has box property with static value to all those objects that don't have hasBox in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map each element that contains `hasBox` to itself and add `hasBox` with a default value to all other elements. The original array isn't changed. You should use `hasOwnProperty` instead of `!item.hasBox` to check if an object has a property otherwise you'll get wrong results for values like `''`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, ...

```js
const items = [
    {},
    {hasBox: undefined},
    {hasBox: true},
    {hasBox: false},
    {hasBox: null},
    {hasBox: ''},
    {hasBox: 0}
];
const updatedArray = items.map(item => 
    !item.hasOwnProperty('hasBox') ? {...item, hasBox: 'default'} : item);
console.log(items);
console.log(updatedArray);
```

Comment: You can also use `Object.assign(item, {hasBox:'default'})` instead of `{...item, hasBox: 'default'}`. It has the added benefit of keeping the same `item` object rather than create a new one, so you can just use a `forEach` rather than a `map` (also helps if `item` is held by something else)

Comment: @divillysausages I don't want to change the original array. I'd use `Object.assign({}, item, {hasBox:'default'})` instead but `{...item, hasBox: 'default'}` is shorter. It would be very confusing to have a variable `updatedArray` but changing the elements of `items`. In my codebase I would even use a library like `immer` or `lodash` to create deep copies.

Comment: "I don't want to change the original array" => `map` gives you a new array fyi, and destructuring `item` gives you new elements in that new array

Comment: @divillysausages You mean like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cj15Px4KOThLWrgY `items` is changed. That's not what most people want. It seems like even you didn't know about this behavior. That's the reason you should pay the price for a copy to avoid such surprises. `map` gives you a flat copy. desctructuring gives you a deeper copy.

Comment: Using a `forEach` and `Object.assign()` will allow you to keep the same `items` array and objects, yes. Using `map` and `{...item}` will return a new copy. I'm assuming that's what you mean?

Comment: @divillysausages I mean I don't want to change `items`. Using `forEach` and `Object.assign` changes `items`. Why would you create a new variable `updatedArray` if the original array is also changed? That's confusing. That's the reason modern libraries use states based on immutable objects.

Comment: Yes, I'm not disagreeing with you? I thought I was fairly clear in my original comment, but in case it's not to anyone reading this, **`forEach` and `Object.assign` will change the array in-situ. That may or may not be what you want**

Comment: @divillysausages I understand what you mean. You want to save one copy. But in my opinion that's bad practice and I wouldn't accept it in a code review. I've seen multiple bugs in different projects in different very experienced teams just because of this. Obviously even you didn't know about this as you stated _"map gives you a new array fyi,"_